# Coding dedicated function Average Filter to color Images C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, average

So basically, I have to code my own function in C++ with OpenCV, that will apply average filter on both gray and color images.

The function returns a Mat Object, have a mat Object and the size of the average filter (3 for 3x3 matrix of filtering for example).

I did this for the moment, it doesn't work, and I don't know how to extend it to color.

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat filtrageMoyen(Mat image, int tailleZonage) {
    Mat imageRetour;
    imageRetour = image.clone();
    Scalar intensite = 0;
    int cadrillage = tailleZonage / 2;
    int valeurMoyenne = 0;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < imageRetour.rows; x++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < imageRetour.cols; y++)
        {
            for (size_t xZonage = 0; xZonage < cadrillage; xZonage++)
            {
                for (size_t yZonage = 0; yZonage < cadrillage; yZonage++)
                {
                    valeurMoyenne += (image.at<unsigned char>(x+xZonage, y + yZonage));
                }
            }
            imageRetour.at<unsigned char>(x, y) = valeurMoyenne;
            valeurMoyenne = 0;
        }
    }
    return imageRetour;

}

int main() {
    Mat img;
    string filename = "imageRickRoll.png";
    img = imread(filename, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    imshow("Image filtree", filtrageMoyen(img, 5));
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Wouldn't it be better to take `image` by `const&` instead of copying it and then `clone()` it? ...or are `Mat` objects reference counted?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yep, they are, it behaves a lot like a shared_ptr.

Comment: Yes it could be better indeed. Thanks :D

Comment: So should I go with ```Mat filtrageMoyen(const Mat& image, int tailleZonage)``` or ```Mat filtrageMoyen(Mat image, int tailleZonage)``` ? And do you have any ideas for my problem ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, the overhead is negligible compared to the 4 nested loops, and it doesn't have any effect on the functionality of the algorithm. | Elaborate on "It doesn't work".

Comment: Okay thanks, for the 4 nested loops, it's the way I have to use it, so I can't really do in another way

Comment: One issue I can immediately see -- you want an "average" filter, but all you do is a sum. Seems like you forgot the divide the sum by number of values in the window. Also, the sum is likely to be greater than 255, so the assignment will overflow.

Comment: Yes I know, but when I divide by the size given in the function parameters, it put it in black, so I don't really understand why

Comment: To explain a little bit more the "It doesn't work" as you are asking :
When I divide the sum by the size * size of matrix filter, It makes the image dark.
Also, if i put another number than 3, it gives an issue : abort() has been called

Comment: OK, [edit] your question and add that information there. Also, provide an example `main()` function showing how you call this function, so we have something to reproduce the problem. The more I look at it, the more issues I see there. | Just for clarification, if `tailleZonage` is set to `3`, it should calculate the average value of pixels in a 3x3 square centered on the current pixel? Do you want this to work only with odd values (1,3,5,...) or should even sizes be handled as well (and how?).

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you test this with a very small image (like 4x4) populated with known pixel intensities, and then step through it in the debugger... or add a lot of tracing, so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, it has to be with odd values, I edited the code. And sorry, I'm a beginner for the moment, it is certainly full of mistakes and issues :(

Comment: OK, I'm trying to make this educational, so for now, I've cleaned up the code (translate variables to English, get rid of the `using namespace`, etc.), did a bit of refactoring, added a bunch of tracing to let you see what's going on, and created a simple 4x4 input image  for testing. I intentionally left all the mistakes there for now. https://pastebin.com/VqxhV559 | BTW, from your latest edit it appears that you're trying this on 5x5 window, which explains why you get a crash -- you're trying to read outside the bounds of the input image.

Comment: Okay, i read what you did, and I understood everything. I Will correct the mistake for mean calculation you let in purpose. But I was wondering how you can entend this to an image with three channels for the three colors, BGR in Opencv ?

Comment: Don't worry about that, we'll get to that eventually. Right now there are several more issues to deal with in order to make this work properly for grayscale. I'm creating another version of the program with annotations where I fix the various issues, give me some time. | For one, if you'll notice in the things it prints out right now, instead of processing a 3x3 area, you only account for a single pixel at the center. Additionally, you don't account for the corner cases - filtering pixels near the edges means that you may try to read outside the bound of the source image, which is a problem.

Comment: OK, here is the next stage, attempting to make it to work for grayscale, with explanations. https://pastebin.com/avP2fnXC Next stage will be making this work for 3-channel input images. It's getting late, so hope you don't mind if  we continue tomorrow. Let me know if you don't understand something I did there.  | Verify that the results make sense. We're treating pixels outside the bounds of the input image to have intensity of 0.

Comment: I didn't read all the comments.... variable naming is broken. rows should go with y, cols should go with x, and indexing should be (y,x)

Comment: So, I just read your different comments, and the last thing you did on pastebin. For the framing from -framing to +framing, that's what I did at first, but it was doing the abort() issue. I understand now that it is associated with the fact that I was trying to take pixels that doesn't exist.

Comment: For the rest of the code, I understand what you did. So thanks a lot for the moment, t's really helpful, I'm discovering that I did a lot of mistakes !

Comment: Also, I add this thing I have to do. The exception for the pixels that we can't access has to be dealt with two kinds of padding, zero padding, so we fill another contour around the image with zeros. And the second way of padding is same padding, so we just add a contour, but filled with the value next to the contour.

Comment: I really tried different things today, but I definitely don't know how to extend it to 3 channels @DanMašek :( Would you help me ?